# Приложение вылетает из-за ошибки в коде

Tags: java, android

По моей задумке приложение через секунду после открытия меняет цвет текста, но выскакивает ошибка, связанная с параметром цвета. Не могу понять, чем вызвана ошибка.

**Мой код:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mainText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainText = findViewById(R.id.textMain);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mainText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0088"));
}
}
```

**Лог ошибки:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference
at com.nikitafront.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)<8 more...> <1 internal call> <2 more...>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка в том, что ты пытаешься найти вью по его id раньше, чем установил разметку с этой вью. Поменяй местами строки 
    `mainText = findViewById(R.id.textMain);` и 
    `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: @Circassian, да, точно, глупо ошибся)
Но, к сожалению, ошибка не ушла

Comment: Если ошибка не ушла - проверьте правильность указанной разметки и ID искомой вьюхи. Также вы замораживаете поток главный, что делать строго не рекомендуется. Если он будет заморожен дольше 5 секунд - приложение выкинет ANR ошибку и предложит приложение закрыть. Используйте для выполенения действия через к-л время TimerTask, RxJava, coroutines, AsyncTask etc

Comment: @ЮрийСПб дело в том, что ошибка вылетает даже если я убираю задержку времени (была мысли, что это причина ошибки, поэтому убирал)

Comment: В таком случае перечитайте первую часть моего предыдущего коммента. У вас null, если вы не там, не тогда (вроде как не ваш уже случай после исправлений после первого коммента под вопросом) или не по тому ID или не в той разметке ищите вьюху. Покажите вашу разметку (текстом содержимое XML файла). Также замените скриншот лога ошибки на его текстовое представление. Картинки плохо подходят для передачи текстовой информации.